# How to remove first two and last two chars in a string?

Tags: c#, string

Is there an easy way to remove the first 2 and last 2 chars in a string?

I have this string:

```
\nTESTSTRING\n
```

How could I easily delete them?

Comment: Your question is wrong. "\n" is ONE char (also noted in a comment below).

Comment: ...unless it's not only the \n character but actually the \r\n character combination that is used as line break on non-*nix systems.

Comment: If you just want to remove \n chars you could use : `str.Replace('\n','');`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
str = str.Substring(2,str.Length-4)
```

Of course you must test that the string contains more than 4 chars before doing this. Also in your case it seems that \n is a single newline character. If all you want to do is remove leading and trailing whitespaces, you should use

```
str.Trim()
```

as suggested by Charles

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question as asked, but it sounds like the OP doesn't realize that \n is the escape for a newline.

Comment: The first part is correct for my use. The second one isn't applicable because I'm using it on HTML, and using the .Trim() doesn't remove the whitespace at all.

Comment: @Manu SubString should be Substring. Its too small of an edit for me to submit

Answer (score 6):

```
// Test string
var str = "\nTESTSTRING\n";

// Number of characters to remove on each end
var n = 2;

// Slimmed string
string slimmed;

if (str.Length > n * 2)
    slimmed = str.Substring(n, str.Length - (n * 2));
else
    slimmed = string.Empty;

// slimmed = "ESTSTRIN"
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you try:

```
 myString.Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myString = myString.SubString(2, myString.Length - 4);
```

Comment: Needs a check for `Length < 4`.

Comment: (myString == ESTSTRIN ) == true

Answer (score 0):

Papuccino1,

If you create an extension method like this:

```
 public static class StringEnumerator {

    public static IEnumerable<String> GetLines(this String source) {
        String line = String.Empty;
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(source);

        while ((line = stringReader.ReadLine()) != null) {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) {
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

your code will be simplified and will be safer (not depending on dangerous index):

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        String someText = "\nTESTSTRING\n";
        String firstLine = someText.GetLines().First();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps,

Ricardo Lacerda Castelo Branco

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string RemoveFirstCharFromString(string Text)
    {
        string[] arr1 = new string[] { "The ", "A " };

        string Original = Text.ToLower();
        if (Text.Length > 4)
        {
            foreach (string match in arr1)
            {
                if (Original.StartsWith(match.ToLower()))
                {
                    //Original = Original.Replace(match.ToLower(), "").TrimStart();
                    Original = Original.Replace(Original.Substring(0, match.Length), "").TrimStart();
                    return Original;
                }
            }
        }
        return Original;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string Origional = TextBox1.Text.Replace(TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 2), "");
Origional += Origional.Replace(Origional.Substring((Origional.Length - 2), 2), "");
```

Comment: is usually helpful to provide some additional explanation instead of only pasting some code

Comment: Shouldn't Origional be Original?  I can't edit, because I'd still be under the 6-character limit.

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple with `Substring` and `Remove` methods, as detailed in [this link](http://vijaysinghnegi.blogspot.in/2014/07/string-first-and-last-character-by.html):

```
string mystring = "122014";

mystring = mystring.Substring(mystring.Length - 4);
Response.Write(mystring.ToString());

//output:2014


mystring = "122014";
string sub = mystring.Remove(mystring.Length - 4);
Response.Write("<br>");
Response.Write(sub.ToString());

//output: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ready to use method. It **takes the char count to trim from left and right**, uses C# 8.0
[Range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#range-operator-) and checks for invalid input:

```cs
static string TrimMargins(string text, int margin)
{
    if (text == null || text.Length < 2 * margin)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return text[margin..^margin];
}
```

Usage:

```cs
string result = TrimMargins("123456", 2);
// result is "34"
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer can be generalized as

```cs
static string TrimMargins(string text, int margin)
{
    if (text == null || text.Length < 2 * margin)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    return text.Substring(margin, text.Length - 2 * margin);
}
```

Usage:

```cs
string result = TrimMargins("123456", 2);
// result is "34"
```