# How can i flatten a nested string?

Tags: c#, vb.net

My method `webClient.DownloadString(URL)` converts the obtained string value to a string. Hence I have a `""result""`. So, how can I convert `""result""` to `"result"`?

Comment: What about `String.Trim("\"")`?

Comment: If you know the string is always enclosed in speech marks then maybe you can [remove the first and last character of the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597583/how-to-remove-first-two-and-last-two-chars-in-a-string).

Comment: _" converts the obtained string value to a string"_ please reread

Comment: Alternatively, can `webClient` read data in the type it receives?
(in this case, it would be a string instead of a nested string)

Comment: Are you sure there's a double quote? Where do you look the data (a dump, the watch, ...)?

Comment: yes, i'm sure. I see it while debugging and when i used the trim method, i don't see the  nested string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String.Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx):

VB.NET:

```
Dim str = webClient.DownloadString(URL)
str = str.Trim(""""c)
```

C#:

```
string str = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
str = str.Trim('"');
```

You can pass multiple characters to it if you want to remove multiple  leading and trailing characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`string.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
myString = myString.Replace("\"\"", "\"");
```

Comment: Both `Trim("\"")` and `Replace("\"\"", "\"")` methods fails with "String constants must end with a double quote"
@ HimBromBeere

Comment: replace is not good option because you will loose any two double quotes that can be in middle of string. Trim is best option also why do you assume it fails? can you provide example? @functional_overflow

Comment: the methods failed in VB.net because it doesn't support this escape character.